# Reconciling Inventory Spreadsheet with Updated Sheet

Tags: merge, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a workbook where one sheet (A) is an old inventory list. On another sheet (B) in the workbook, someone copied several of the columns from sheet A. Then they went around and updated the inventory on that sheet manually--some things that weren't written down properly were corrected, some equipment was added, etc. Some things may be missing from sheet B (I'm not sure why).

What's the best way to reconcile these two worksheets onto sheet A? There are few enough items that if I have to do this manually I can, but there are enough items that that seems inefficient.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are the number and headings of the columns the same? It is possible to use formulas to detect differences, remove all non-changed rows on sheet B and then work through the changed ones.

Comment: The headings are the same but they are not numbered identically. Of the 18 columns in A, columns 1-4, 7-8 are in B.

I tried creating a pivot table. I was hoping to figure out how to make it match the "Asset #" column in both sheets and then use that to either show me 'Asset #'s existing in one but not the other, or to show me the ones where there are matches with the data in other columns that are named the same have different values.

I did a lot of this manually over the weekend, but I'd feel a lot better if there were a programmatic way to do this both in the future and to check myself.